# Does Instagram provide ready-to-use Follow buttons (with colors, sizes, texts, counters, so forth)?

Tags: instagram

Like Facebook or Twitter buttons. I can't find any information [in their documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/). Google Search doesn't have much either.

Answer (score 1):

Recently there isn't Follow button available, so people wish to follow site owner's IG account must manually find him on IG and they follow (or request)